# how to find tangent at time t in natural cubic spline

Tags: math, geometry, 3d, interpolation, spline

I used Tim Lamber's algorithm to draw a natural spline cubic curve.

[NatCubic](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~lambert/splines/NatCubic.java) class

NatCubic class compute the coefficients of the cubics (a b c d) of an array of points.

a + b*u + c*u^2 + d*u^3 0<=u <1

and Cubic class compute the points on the curve at time t in [0-1].

b in Cubic class is the derivatives at the knots at i

My question is: how to find the tangent at t >0 <1

Thank you!

PS :

for clarify my question, I search the tangent at time t, eg 0.5 
to using pre-computed coeficients (abcd) of each control point.
This is to avoid calculating the point(t+1) to find the tangent by, y(i +1) - y(i-1)

sorry for my poor english.

[you can see in this picture that I want to do](http://gilles.macabies.perso.sfr.fr//tangent.jpg)

Comment: Did Sir Isaac Newton die just so that questions like this could be asked?

Comment: t> 0 <1  ??
Did you mean: 0<t<1  ?

Each point gives you a vector in 3D. Usually the normal to that vector gives you tangent to that point.
If you want tangent on surface then any two adjacent points give you a vector which is actually a tangent on the surface between these two points.

Answer (score -1):

Sont know if I well understood your question.

(EDIT)

Slope = b + 2c*u + 3d*u^2

then for the tanget use

(y - yo) = m * (x - x0)

where y0 is your spline value at point x0
and m is the slope at x0

Comment: This is just blatantly wrong. A tangent is a line, not a number. You probably mean "Slope of the tangent = ...", in which case the formula is incorrect.

Comment: Ok Yes.... BUt once you have the slope then you have the tanget (I'll edit my post)

Comment: Derivative of u^3 is **NOT** u^2, and derivative of u^2 is **NOT** u.

Comment: to clarify my question, I search the tangent at time t, eg 0.5

using pre-computed coeficients (abcd) of each control point.

This is to avoid calculating the point (t +1)

to find  the tangent by, x (i +1) - x (i-1)

Comment: U can only have your slope with pre-computed coefficents as shown in my answer... The you need to add an offset. The tanget is thus y = m*x - m*x0 + y0. Just calculate y0 with your function.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try and make you a return :)

Comment: @user1012750: Although that now your slope calculation is correct you still miss one crucial thing: That (y - y0)/(x - x0) = m is essentially a derivative. I.e. dy/dx of the given bezier spline. What the OP want's are just normalized dy and dx, not that differences. I.e: dy/dx = m, if m > 1 let dy=1 so 1/dx = m => dx = 1/m, if m < 1 let dx = 1, dy = m. Last step, normalize the vector (dx,dy) to length 1.

Comment: As I understand what the user wants is just the calculation of the tangent. So the algorithm is basically in 2 steps: 1- Calculate the slope. 2-Calculate the offset. Just as I explained

Comment: you can see in this picture that I want to do  http://gilles.macabies.perso.sfr.fr//tangent.jpg

Comment: I may help you but i need to check your code... Looking at your picture I don't understand how points are generated. Example : how are PT0 and PT4 generated by your function? What is the input?

Comment: @macgile  You need to add the code to your question not to this answer.